# MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Lost In JSON Encode from MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, objectid

I am having a problem where I retrieving an ObjectID from a MongoDB database , but the '_id' value is always disappearing when ran though json_encode. All the other data in my array is present. My code is as such:

```
$data = array('_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID(), 'title' => 'abc123');

 //ID Is there!
 print_r($data);
 //ID IS EMPTTYy!!!
 print_r(json_encode($data));
 exit();
```

The results look like this:

```
Array ( [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object ( [oid] => 56d9d2687e34d70d3a304c46 ) [title] => abc123 ) 

{"_id":{},"title":"abc123"}
```

At the very least, the _id should have an object or number in it. My question is what is stripping out the \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID and how can I get it to stay?

Comment: Please post the output you're getting, and the output you're expecting.

Comment: Ok, posted the outputs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is what is stripping out the \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID

`json_encode` will encode only `public` properties of encountered objects.

> how can I get it to stay?

You could cast it to string before encoding.

Comment: Yes, converting it to a string does work but that feels like design flaw with the developers who created it.

Comment: @DevinDixon If anything it's related to how the JSON encoder works, and it's working as intended. malarzm is canonically correct.

Comment: @Sammitch Yes malarzm answer is correct and I wrote a recursive json function that converts all the items to a string. The design flaw I was referring is a lot of the functions that have been released in MongoDB PHP latest update. Just personal opionion, I like minimialist approach to development where I create write my abstraction layers as needed. A lot of the PHP Mongo features have abstraction layers which adds more time for learning their implementation and having to rewrite code.

Answer (score 0):

example code for @malarzm's answer:

```
$output = [];
foreach( $data as $key => $val){
    $val->_id = strval($val->_id);
    $output[$key] = $val;
}

echo json_encode( $output );
```